# Android Unit Test : Instrumentation failed due to a class error

Tags: java, android, robotium

I am running a test using Robotium on an android emulator. When I run my test I get an error saying  "Test failed to run to completion.Reason: Instrumentation failed due to

```
 com.example.android.businesslogic.TestBL$1
```

I check the logcat for error's and I see following

```
 W/ActivityManager( 51) com.example.android.businesslogic.TestBL$1
 W/ActivityManager( 51) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.android.businesslogic.TestBL$1
```

My application has no error and can run smoothly, its just when I do the unit test that I get into this. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete and Create the test project again with proper class paths and the path to apk. You just have to create a test project and include any external Jar's if you have. This worked for me.